# Decrease width of input in HTML

Tags: html, css

So I have an input tag in HTML, and I need to decrease its width to (let's just say) 80% of its normal width. I've tried setting `width:80%` but that didn't work. I would prefer solutions using only HTML/CSS, but I'm open to anything. My Google searches came up with results to change the width to a fixed amount like 50 pixels, not relative to its normal width. Thanks!

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to specify the size of an element in relation to its initial 'default' size without using JavaScript; with CSS you can specify a length absolutely, in relation to its parent element, in relation to the viewport or relative to the font size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get the current input width (myInputWidth). Multiply it by some factor (0.8). Then modify the width.

```
var myInputWidth = (document.getElementById("myInput").offsetWidth);

document.getElementById("myInput").style.width = myInputWidth * 0.8 + "px";
```

You can check out an example of this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k9n3gLab/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple with CSS. Check this out!

```css
.input-box{
  width:100px
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" class="input-box" type="text">
```

This is what you want hope this helps you.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your input element in a container, set a width of said container and then modify the width of the input in percentages.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#input {
  width: calc(0.8 * 500px); /* 80% = 0.8 && 500px is the input element's initial width. Just for example I took 500px */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this for one input box only then you can add [Inline Css](https://www.javatpoint.com/inline-css)

```
<input type="text" id="input" style="width:100px">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a block element around.
For example:

```
<div class="myBox">
<input class="myInput" type="text">
</div>

.myBox {
display: block;
width: 100px;
}

.myInput {
width: 80%;
}
```

This method your input take 80% width of your parent item (div, myBox).